# How many observations are required to achieve a particular confidence interval for the mean?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

> Suppose that the standard deviation of an observation in a given population is
> known to be $\sigma = 15$.
>
> How many observations in a sample is needed to estimate $\overline{x}$ (the mean of the sample) within $±5$ of the population mean $ \mu$ with $99$% confidence?

This has me stumped I don't know where to start, any assistance in finding the sample mean $\overline{x}$, population mean $ \mu$ how to find $±5$ of that mean and amount of observations needed... would be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't given any indication of what your difficulty is, and that makes it impossible to know how to help you.  For example, do you know what a confidence interval is?  Do you know how to calculate a standard deviation?  Do you know any formulas that relate these things? Someone here could waste a lot of time explaining the wrong thing, so this type of question is poorly received on this site.

Comment: Just to follow up on the above comment, you can edit the post by clicking the “edit” button below what you’ve already written. You should explain what your difficulty is and why you are interested in this particular question. This makes it much more likely that you will receive an answer and much less likely that this question is closed for failing to meet the community guidelines.

Comment: copy that, post amended

Comment: The only thing you can do is Chebyshev's inequality